# 5k eggs in my basket changing to 2k eggs

Tags: pokemon-go

On several occasions, a 5k egg in my basket has suddenly become a 2k egg. This has happened when both when my basket had an empty slot in it (just after hatching an egg but before getting a new one from a pokestop) and when my basket was full.  There seems to be no pattern to which egg changes.  I've reported this to Niantic as a bug, but don't know anyone else who has had this happen to them and can't find anything online about other people's experiences with this.  Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Are you 100% positive the order didn't just change? When your eggs aren't being incubated, the order shifts at random whenever you open the menu.

Comment: @Vemonus: I've noticed that too and was my first thought as well.

Comment: @Ellesedil I mean it could very well be a new bug but since I haven't seen anything else on it, I'm inclined to think it may just be confusion

Answer (score 1):

There is no evidence of eggs changing types (distances), and several comments echo the experienced shuffling of eggs in the inventory. The most likely scenario is not that the eggs changed, but rather that their order did.

If you dispute this, note *the number* of eggs of each type (include screenshots) before and after this shift.